# Should I downvote a feasible but not efficient answer?

Tags: discussion

For example if an answer can solve the OP's problem, but also has some obvious defect of efficiency. Should answers like these be downvoted?

Comment: Is the answer useful (for the OP, for future visitors) despite the defect? Can the answer be applied as a solution in the context of the problem described in the question?

Comment: In addition to what rene has said, you could also leave a comment explaining the defect and how the answer can be improved.

Comment: If you notice an obvious defect with the code, why not mention it to the author? This is why we have comments. Want to draw attention to that comment, downvote. This is why votes can be changed after a post is edited... If it get resolved, and you feel it becomes a quality post, either delete, or change you vote..

Comment: I don't understand the score on this question...

Answer (score 4):

If it has an *"obvious defect"*, is the answer *really* feasible?

In the end, you're allowed to vote however you want.*
If you *should* is up to you. It's your vote.

<sub>(*provided you don't game the system: voting rings, serial votes etc)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For downvoting an answer should be "not useful".
There are two kinds of usefulness, for the OP and for the other users of StackOverflow.
For an answer, the usefulness for the rest of SO is less important than for a question;
because if the question is useful then anything which answers it is useful enough.

A question which can in no way ever be useful for anybody else deserves a downvote. Opinions divide on whether an answer to a really bad question is bad just because of that, but a question  cannot be so bad by just only being useful for the OP.

So I find answers which solve OPs problem (including that they are just efficient enough to actually be useable) do not deserve a downvote for not being useful.
They might of course have other defects.
A solution in an answer can of course be so terribly inefficient that it is not really useable. It is not easy to define a maximum duration generally, but we probably agree that for any desired effect, there is a time nobody will be prepared to wait for it. There is a little realtime problem in every goal.
(Using this understanding of realtime: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing)

But an answer can still be useful enough not to be downvoted, even if there are more efficient solutions imaginable.

In short, only downvote if the answer is so inefficient that it is seriously unuseable.

If it is inefficient, but does the job, then I would just not upvote it.
Especially if a more efficient solution is shown in a neighbouring answer, this is good enough  to help future readers classifying the answers. Maybe you could create such an answer (but I understand that this meta question is not about "I know a more efficient solution.").

On the other hand, (down-) voting is anonymous for a reason. If you feel an answer deserves a downvote, including that you are prepared to spend a little reputation for expressing your feeling, then downvote. Your feeling is important and valued by StackOverflow concept. It is all the reason you need and there are far worse reasons.
If you could give a reason in a comment, to help the answerer understand and maybe even improve, that would be very appreciated, too. But you do not have to.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on in what way the code is inefficient.

If the answer uses a loop instead of some kind of array function then I just comment and say you can do it like this.
Then it's up to he/she to change the answer.

If the answer by some reason tries to reinvent the wheel by say... create a own Unix time function.
Then I'd downvote and leave a comment that Unix time does exist.

I know my two examples are to some degree similar, but what I mean is that it depends on the situation and answer.
Another example is using regex to substring a string, that's a downvote.
It's such an obvious and large error you shouldn't do.
But looping instead of using array functions are common mistakes.